# How to replace default function content with my custom function in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Recently, I tried to use Rails custom template to build the custom template when I new a app.
For example : I replace the default password lenghth with the following code

```
   gsub_file 'config/initializers/devise.rb', /config.password_length = 8..128/ do
       <<-RUBY
           config.password_length = 1..128
       RUBY
   end
```

however, if I want to replace

```
def confirm
    @message = "AAA"

end  

def confirm(email)
    @message = "Thank you for confirmation!"
    mail(:to => email, :subject => "Registered")  
end
```

how could I do, can give me some direction,
Thanks you very much~

Comment: why do you want to replace it when you are using the second method with arguments why don't you just overload the function and use the one you want?

Comment: In ruby ,you just need to redefine the method you want to replace.

Comment: @Bigxiang but how could you find the original method and insert new function after it?

Comment: I put an answer below, if you have any question, just comment it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby ,You can redefine a class anywhere. You can test it in the console

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > "a".inspect
 => "\"a\"" 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > class String
1.9.3-p125 :003?>   def inspect(n)
1.9.3-p125 :004?>     puts "hey#{n}"
1.9.3-p125 :005?>     end
1.9.3-p125 :006?>   end
 => nil
1.9.3-p125 :008 > "a".inspect(1)
hey1
 => nil
```

In above example, you redefine the inspect method in String.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def confirm(email)
  @message = "AAA"
  mail(:to => email, :subject => "Registered")  
end
```